# How to pass a parameter from JSP to Struts 2 action

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, parameters, struts2

I have an application and I want to pass item `id` to the action every time the button for that item is pressed.

### My JSP :

```jsp
<s:submit  value="addToCart" action="addToCart" type="submit">
<s:param name="id" value="%{#cpu.id}" />
</s:submit>
```

### Action:

```
public class ProductsCPU extends BaseAction implements Preparable, SessionAware {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2124421844550008773L;

private List colors = new ArrayList<>();
private List cpus;
private String id;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

When I print id to console, it has the `null` value. What is the problem?

Comment: why don't you pass parameter in hidden field like `<s:hidden name="id" value="%{#cpu.id}" />`

Comment: if I pass parameter using hidden tag, id value is composed of all ids of items, in my case 1,2. I want it to be either 1, either 2.

Comment: i am asking to do something like this `<s:submit value="addToCart" action="addToCart" type="submit">
        <s:hidden name="val1" value="1"></s:hidden>
      </s:submit>`

Comment: I did. but the finally id contains all the items id. This is my submit:                                                              <s:submit  value="addToCart" action="addToCart" type="submit">                  <s:hidden name="id" value="%{#cpu.id}" />
</s:submit>

Comment: did not understand what you want to tell by your comment??

Comment: if I use the hidden tag, id has the value "1,2". I want it to be only one value, not all.

Comment: but your question is not clear enough in that case.Add more details as how you are placing the item, what you mean by `button for that item`, since you are using submit button, i assumed that you have items inside a form with a single submit button

Answer (score 1):

This should do :

```
<s:url id="myurl" action="addToCart">
    <s:param name="id" value="%{#cpu.id}" />
</s:url>
<s:submit  value="addToCart" action="%{myurl}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use form element.

```
<form action="passId>
    <s:hidden name="id" value="%{#cpu.id}" />
    <s:submit  value="addToCart" action="addToCart" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't parametrize [`<s:submit>` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/submit-tag.html) with `<s:param>` tag like in your code using  the param tag in the body of  the submit tag.

You also don't want to add `<hidden>` field because you got multiple values submitted to the action. This is because many hidden fields are rendered with the same name. You could use *only* one field and update its value before submitting a form.

Probably you have used wrong tag to pass a parameter to the action. You can use anchor tag and parametrize it with `<s:param>` tag.

The second way is to use JavaScript to modify `action` attribute. In this way you can also use a `<button>` tag.

Third way is not recommended because it requires to use multiple forms one per each link. In this way you add a parameter to the form action attribute directly.

Below is the code for the options mentioned above.

## 3-in-1:

```xml
<s:form name="myForm13" namespace="/" action="save?message=Hello param 3" theme="simple">
  <br/><s:a cssClass="btn btn-primary" action="test"><s:param name="message">Hello param 1</s:param>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Go&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</s:a>
  <br/><s:a href="#" cssClass="btn btn-warning" onclick="myForm13.action='test?message=Hello param 2';myForm13.submit()">Submit</s:a>
  <br/><s:submit cssClass="btn btn-danger" action="test"/>    
</s:form>
```

---

Comment: Parameters are passed 3in1 but there's another one that you should find it yourself.