# Passing parameter from view to action in Struts 2

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts2

I am trying to pass a value in JavaScript variable (i.e an access token from Facebook) from the view section of the framework to action where the corresponding Java object variable is stored.

What are the possible ways to do this?

Comment: take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110221/how-can-i-pass-value-from-javascript-to-a-java-class-in-struts2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769195/pass-parameter-from-jsp-to-struts-2-action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a hidden field and save the value in it. Access the action via submitting a form like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16384229/573032) answer. The example of saving a value to a hidden field using jQuery

```
<s:hidden name="myHiddenField"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function saveValue(value) {
    $('input:hidden[name="myHiddenField"]').val(value);
  }
</script>
```

In the action class you should have a property  for `myHiddenField`

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {
  private String myHiddenField;
  //getters and setters here 
  ...
}
```

now you configure the action to execute using `defaultStack` of interceptors and when you submit the form the field will be populated to the action object.