# How to invoke a method on submit button in Struts 2 using convention plugin?

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts2-convention-plugin, dmi

In the following piece of code about Struts action class,

```java
@Namespace("/admin_side")
@ResultPath("/WEB-INF/content")  // Default.

public final class TestAction extends ActionSupport implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String SUCCESS = "success";

    private String name;
    private String email;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    @Action(value="test",results={@Result(name="success",location="Test.jsp")})
    public String execute() throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("name = "+name);
        System.out.println("email = "+email);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    // Some annotations to map this method to <s:submit>
    public String postAction()
    {
        System.out.println("postAction() invoked.");
        System.out.println("name = "+name);
        System.out.println("email = "+email);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

I want to invoke the `postAction()` method on the given submit button like so,

```jsp
<s:form action="test">
    <s:textfield id="name" name="name" label="Enter your name"/>
    <s:textfield id="email" name="email" label="Enter your email"/>

    <s:submit value="Submit" method="postAction"/>
</s:form>
```

---

I have seen some questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13333196/1391249) but all of them use XML configurations in `struts.xml`.

How to make it possible *using* [convention plugin](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/convention)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `namespace` attribute because your action is mapped with `@Namespace`.

```
<s:form namespace="/admin_side" action="test">
    <s:textfield id="name" name="name" label="Enter your name"/>
    <s:textfield id="email" name="email" label="Enter your email"/>

    <s:submit value="Submit" method="postAction"/>
</s:form>
```

If this doesn't work in the latest version according to [WW-4023](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4023) then you can invoke a method directly

```
<s:url var="myUrl" namespace="/admin_side" action="test" method="postAction"/> 
<s:form action="%{#myUrl}">
    <s:textfield id="name" name="name" label="Enter your name"/>
    <s:textfield id="email" name="email" label="Enter your email"/>

    <s:submit value="Submit"/>
</s:form>
```

or configure [`params` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/parameters-interceptor.html) parameter `excludeParams` to remove `method` parameter from excluded parameters.

Note, either you use [DMI](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-configuration.html#dynamic-method-invocation) and the methods above or don't use it, in this case you should map an action to the method and don't use attributes `method` or `submit` tag's `method` and `action` as the issue above restrict using special parameters. If you have multiple submit buttons if you follow that restriction you have to dynamically change `form` tag's action attribute using JavaScript `onclick` event.

Comment: How to get rid of this warning - `WARNING: Parameter [action:postAction] is on the excludeParams list of patterns!`? [Google](https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr&ei=FG64UrzYGsK4rgf4sIHABQ#q=WARNING:+Parameter+is+on+the+excludeParams+list+of+patterns!)  did not lead me to the solution. I do not know how to configure interceptor using annotations. Can you give an example, please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16604527/573032, http://stackoverflow.com/a/15922028/573032

Comment: i am new to java web its legacy project , i just upgarded my strtuts to 2.5 from 2.3 
now i cant invoke method from my s:submit instead i am using action to invoke the method of action .
but their are many buttons so i need to make lot of change any other solution such that my project will work with method invocation over action in jsp

Comment: If you updated your project to the newer version of struts then you should knew new features of the struts version it gives to you. For this purpose I always recommend to read release notes. Many useful suggestions you can find in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58148759/573032) answer. Another [exampe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23415759/573032) is about mapping submit buttons to the actions that are mapper to the methods. A lot of ways to change the forms action attribute exist like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41203329/573032) answer. You@babbin should practice many examples.

Answer (score 2):

Different methods are achievable by:

1. moving the `@Action` annotation from method-level to class-level:

   ```
   @Action(value="test",results={@Result(name="success",location="Test.jsp")})
   public final class TestAction extends ActionSupport implements Serializable {
   ```
2. renaming the `execute()` method into something else, eg. `test()`:

   ```
   public String test() throws Exception {
       System.out.println("name = "+name);
       System.out.println("email = "+email);
       return SUCCESS;
   }

   public String postAction() {
       System.out.println("postAction() invoked.");
       System.out.println("name = "+name);
       System.out.println("email = "+email);
       return SUCCESS;
   }
   ```

From [the documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/convention-plugin.html#ConventionPlugin-Actionannotation):

> **Applying @Action and @Actions at the class level**
>
> There are circumstances when this is desired, like when using Dynamic
>   Method Invocation. If an execute method is defined in the class, then
>   it will be used for the action mapping, otherwise the method to be
>   used will be determined when a request is made (by Dynamic Method
>   Invocation for example)

, and obviously by enabling Dynamic Method Invocation in Struts.xml.

**But this should be avoided**; read this article to understand why: <kbd>[Making Struts2 app more secure: disable DMI](http://security.coverity.com/blog/2013/Oct/making-struts2-app-more-secure-disable-dynamic-method-invocation.html)</kbd>.
<sub>Note that Struts2 Maven archetypes already has DMI set to false, because it is discouraged.</sub>

Then, you should turn off DMI, and start using multiple Actions instead of multiple methods, by simply annotating the other Action's methods too, and using different `action` attributes in the `<s:submit/>` button :

```
@Action(value="test",results={@Result(name="success",location="Test.jsp")})
public String test() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("name = "+name);
    System.out.println("email = "+email);
    return SUCCESS;
}

@Action(value="postAction",results={@Result(name="success",location="Test.jsp")})
public String postAction() {
    System.out.println("postAction() invoked.");
    System.out.println("name = "+name);
    System.out.println("email = "+email);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

and in JSP:

```
<s:form namespace="/admin_side">
    <s:textfield id="name"  name="name"  label="Enter your name"  />
    <s:textfield id="email" name="email" label="Enter your email" />

    <s:submit value="Submit to test()"       action="test"       />
    <s:submit value="Submit to postAction()" action="postAction" />
</s:form>
```

---

EDIT: Since `Struts 2.3.15.3`, you need to explicitly enable the `action:` suffix with:

```
<constant name="struts.mapper.action.prefix.enabled" value="true"/>
```

Because it won't work by default.

Comment: I have put this property, `struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation=false` to disable DMI under the `WEB-INF/classes/struts.properties` file but the method is never invoked in my case. Instead, I always get a warning like - `Dec 23, 2013 11:15:02 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor warn
WARNING: Parameter [action:postAction!postAction] is on the excludeParams list of patterns!`.

Comment: Is your JSP exactly like mine ?

Comment: Yes it is the same as in your answer.

Comment: @AndreaLigios: Since 2.3.15.3, actually.

Comment: I hit that now by jumping from 2.3.15.2 to 2.3.16... so many changes after the summer security bugs O_o