# How to exclude the submit action from a list of parameters in Struts 2?

Tags: jsp, configuration, struts2, dmi

I'm trying to exclude a submit action from a parameter list.

**The following is the action class:**

```java
@Namespace("/admin_side")
@ResultPath("/WEB-INF/content")
@InterceptorRefs({
    @InterceptorRef(value="validation", params={"excludeMethods", "test"}),
    @InterceptorRef(value="params", params={"excludeParams", "action:postAction"})})
public final class TestAction extends ActionSupport implements Serializable, ValidationAware
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String SUCCESS = "success";

    private String name;

    @Action(value = "test", results = {
    @Result(name="success", location="Test.jsp"),
    @Result(name = "input", location = "Test.jsp")})
    public String test() throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("name = "+name);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    @Action(value = "postAction", results = {
    @Result(name="success", location="Test.jsp"),
    @Result(name = "input", location = "Test.jsp")})
    public String postAction()
    {
        System.out.println("Post invoked");
        System.out.println("name = "+name);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    @RequiredStringValidator(type= ValidatorType.FIELD, message = "The name is required.")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void validate()
    {
        if(!hasErrors()&&name.length()<2)
        {
            addFieldError("name", "The name must compose of 2 letters.");
        }
    }
}
```

**The `Test.jsp` page:**

```jsp
<s:form namespace="/admin_side" action="test" validate="true">
    <s:textfield id="name" name="name" label="Name"/>
    <s:submit id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit" action="postAction"/>
</s:form>
```

The generated HTML code for `<s:submit>` would be like as follows.

```html
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="action:postAction" value="Submit"/>
```

---

The `@InterceptorRef` above the class:

```
@InterceptorRef(value="params", params={"excludeParams", "action:postAction"})
```

doesn't seem to work. The method `postAction()` is never invoked causing the following warning to be issued.

> Dec 24, 2013 10:49:16 PM
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor warn
> WARNING: Parameter [action:postAction] is on the excludeParams list of
> patterns!

---

In the `struts.properties` file, I have the following properties until now.

```
struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation=false
struts.devMode=false
struts.ui.theme=simple

struts.convention.package.locators=actions
struts.convention.action.suffix=Controller
struts.convention.action.mapAllMatches=true

struts.convention.result.path=/WEB-INF/content //No need. It is the default.
struts.mapper.action.prefix.enabled=true
```

I'm using Struts 2.3.16.

---

Why doesn't it exclude the submit button's parameter? How to invoke the `postAction()` method, when `<s:submit>` is clicked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why doesn't it exclude the submit button's parameter?

Because this parameter is in the `excludeParams` list of the `params` interceptor in the `defaultStack` which your action is referenced by default.

> How to invoke the postAction() method, when `<s:submit>` is clicked?

In this question you ask how to invoke a method (not an action). The difference between the action and method the first is mapped to a specified URL using a namespace and action name. So, to invoke a method other than an action you should turn [DMI](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-configuration.html#dynamic-method-invocation) on. Struts, since 2.3.16 turned off this option. The following configuration constant to use in `struts.xml`:

```
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="true"/>
```

and use a `method` attribute instead of `action` attribute.

```
<s:form namespace="/admin_side" action="test">
  <s:submit value="Submit" method="postAction"/>
</s:form>
```

as I already told in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20746418/573032) answer.

If you don't want to use DMI, then you have an option to enable `action:` prefix to the parameter

```
<constant name="struts.mapper.action.prefix.enabled" value="true"/>
```

and use an action mapped to the method `postAction`

```
<s:form namespace="/admin_side" action="test">
  <s:submit value="Submit" action="postAction"/>
</s:form>
```

and use annotation without `params.excludeParams`.

```
@InterceptorRef(value="defaultStack" params={"validation.excludeMethods", "test"})
```

The warning that `action:postAction` parameter is on exclude list still persist, but it appears only if the `struts.devMode=true`. You shouldn't worry about it because it warns all parameters from the `excludeParams` list that passed through. To turn off `devMode` you should set

```
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
```

Comment: Actually, I want the method `postAction()` to be mapped by a given `action` of `<s:submit>` (not `method`), since DMI is discouraged. This interceptor above the action class - `@InterceptorRef(value="defaultStack", params={"params.excludeParams", "action:postAction", "validation.excludeMethods", "test"})})` still cannot remove this warning - `WARNING: Parameter [action:postAction] is on the excludeParams list of patterns!`. I cannot find relavent/suitable examples on the internet.

Comment: Then it issues this warning - `WARNING: Parameter [action:postAction] didn't match acceptedPattern pattern!`

Comment: Then it causes these warnings to be issued : `WARNING: Parameter [action:postAction] didn't match acceptParams list of patterns!` and `WARNING: Parameter [name] didn't match acceptParams list of patterns!`

Comment: I have tried this : `@InterceptorRef(value="defaultStack", params={"params.excludeParams", "^action:(?!postAction$)\\w*$", "params.acceptParamNames", "action:postAction"})`. It shows the warnings as indicated by the previous comment.

Comment: This `@InterceptorRef(value="defaultStack", params={"params.excludeParams", "^action:(?!postAction$)\\w*$",  "params.acceptParamNames", "^action:(?!postAction$)\\w*$","params.acceptParamNames", "name",}` and this `@InterceptorRef(value="defaultStack", params={"params.excludeParams", "action:postAction",  "params.acceptParamNames", "action:postAction","params.acceptParamNames", "name",}` both issuse the same warning : `WARNING: Parameter [action:postAction] didn't match acceptParams list of patterns!`

Comment: Is it really possible to map an action of `<s:submit>` to a method in a corresponding action class? It doesn't seem possible. You seem to have been using the Struts framework for a long time and must have faced and solved this problem in the past, a long time ago! How did you actually solve it? Could you please tell me?

Comment: I thought you put me in the wrong direction, see updated answer.

Comment: I have done according to the update but the method in the action class, `postAction()` is never invoked. Removed `excludeParams`, set `struts.mapper.action.prefix.enabled` to true in `struts.properties` (yes, the system is able to find `struts.properties` on the classpath, I have verified it).

Comment: No really sorry. It works according the updated answer. The method was not invoked only because of validations. I was submitting the page without any values in the fields preventing it from being validated. Thank you very much and sorry for much concerned.

Comment: It should be invoked, If you have validation errors in the validate method then it will not invoke, the INPUT result is returned.

Comment: Does activating `struts.mapper.action.prefix.enabled` opens any security vulnerability?