# How to align two submit buttons?

Tags: jsp, struts2

```jsp
<s:form action="download1" name="regform" id="formSelectOne"  theme="simple">
    <td  valign="top" align="right" >
        <s:submit value="View coc1  " theme="simple" />
    </td>
</s:form>

<s:form action="download2" name="regform" id="formSelectOne"  theme="simple">
    <td  valign="top" align="center">   
         <s:submit value="View doc2" theme="simple" />
    </td>  
</s:form>
```

The buttons are shown side by side, but I need to display the first on the right and the second on the center. How to do that?

Comment: Please take your time to describe better the question you are asking. Your code was messy, your description even worse. And I'm still not sure if my edit is respecting what you are actually asking (that was tagged only struts2, while struts2 fits very little, only for the theme part). And BTW, why on earth do you put your first button as first if you want it on the right ? (unless your site is RTL)

Comment: Why dont you put forms inside the cells(`td`)?

Comment: Why not to use links instead of empty forms with submit?

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to have two forms on the page to submit different actions (methods).

Since the beginning, Struts has a technique to dispatch submit buttons to different actions. In the latest version it's performed via the `submit` tag, that is used to build the action URL from the attributes such as `action` or `method`.

As you are using a `simple` theme on the `form` tag, it's inherited to all input fields. It's not necessary to apply the same theme individually.

If you are using a `table` HTML tag to design your form elements it's substantial to put these buttons inside the same record `tr` tag having `white-space:nowrap;` CSS style.  For example

```jsp
<s:form  name="regform" id="regform" theme="simple">
<table style="width:100%;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tr style="white-space:nowrap;">
    <td style="width:50%;" valign="top" align="right" >
        <s:submit action="download2" value="View coc2"/>
    </td>
    <td style="width:50%;" valign="top" align="right" >
        <s:submit action="download1" value="View coc1"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
<table>
</s:form>
```

---

To have the `action` attribute being worked see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20772170/573032) answer to learn how to enable an action prefix in `struts.xml` to be able to use `action` attribute of the `s:submit` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Add the style attribute in both forms.
because when you start a form tag it usually breaks the line and start from new line.
so adding the below attribute will help you..

```
style="float:left;"
```

Comment: Thanks For this but in the above code where it placed..pls replay

Comment: add the style attribute in "both form elements" like below         <s:form action="download1" name="regform" id="formSelectOne"  theme="simple" style="float:left;"> </s:form>