# Two buttons in <s:form> to decide in the action class

Tags: java, forms, jsp, button, struts2

Is it possible to do something like this?

```jsp
<s:form action="formAction1" namespace="/form1">
  <s:form action="formAction2" namespace="/form2">
    <s:textfield name="user"/>
    <s:password name="pwd" />
    <s:submit name="sub1" value="start1">
    <s:submit name="sub2" value="start2">
  </s:form>
</s:form>
```

i.e. if I click `start1` button, then `formAction1` will be submitted,
else when `start2` is clicked, then `formAction2` will be submitted.
Actually I want to have **2 different actions** on **2 different buttons** in a **single form**.

I *don't* want to use url `<s:url>` tag.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13343954/1700321.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible in HTML, nor in Struts2. You should not have nested forms, but you can use several forms on the page.

```jsp
<s:form>
 <s:textfield name="user"/>
 <s:password name="pwd" />
 <s:submit name="sub1" value="start1" action="formAction1">
 <s:submit name="sub2" value="start2" action="formAction2">
</s:form>
```

Also see [How to align two submit buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22171770/573032). There's also information how to configure Struts2 to use action prefix.

Comment: @AbhishekRaj If this answer helped you to solve your problem you should mark it as accepted. If you have a question see [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible as you have shown in your code; but you can have a one form with multiple buttons & different action can be perform on each button.

you can achieve it by using following code

```
<s:form method="post" action="mySubmitAction">
    // your form fields
    <s:submit value="Submit"/>
    <s:submit value="Clear" action="myClearAction"/>
</form>
```

Here if you click on first button `mySubmitAction` will be called.

If you click on second button `myClearAction` will be called(as we have provided `action` attribute in second button, instead of `mySubmitAction` action `myClearAction` action will be called).

You can access all the form field in both actions.

Hope this will help you.