# Why method prefix not working in Struts 2.3.32

Tags: forms, jsp, struts2, action-mapping, dmi

I use Struts 2.3.32 and this is the code.

**methodPrefix.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <s:form action="methodPrefix" theme="simple">
        name: <br/>
        <s:textfield name="name"/>
        <br><br>
        <s:submit value="Create Person"/>
        <s:submit name="method:cancel" value="Cancel"/>
    </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**MethodPrefixAction.java**

```
   public class MethodPrefixAction 
    {
        private String name;
        private String message;
        
        public String execute() throws Exception
        {
            message = name + " create";
            return "success";
        }
        public String cancel() throws Exception
        {
            message = "cancel";
            return "success";
        }
        
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }
        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }
    }
```

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.mapper.action.prefix.enabled" value="true" />
     
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="">
        <action name="goMethodPrefixPage">
            <result>/chapter4/methodPrefix.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="methodPrefix" class="example.chapter4.MethodPrefixAction">
            <result>/chapter4/methodPrefixResult.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

when I push `Cancel` button, It do not call `cancel()` method, just call `execute()` method.

I don't know why `method:` prefix not work.

I searched a lot, and I know `method:` prefix configuration is false by default in Struts 2.3.32, so I used a constant..... but it did not work

Comment: Try to use `<s:cancel` tag instead of `method:cancel`. Add `cancellable="true"` to `<action name="methodPrefix"` in struts.xml

Comment: It does not work. just error occured <s:cancel> and cancellable both side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This constant

```
<constant name="struts.mapper.action.prefix.enabled" value="true" />
```

works only for `action:` prefix, not a `method:` prefix. So you should use the `action` attribute to submit tag.

```
<s:submit action="cancel" value="Cancel"/>
```

**Note:** If you have [DMI](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-configuration.html#dynamic-method-invocation) turned off the `action:` prefix is still available.

Comment: then how can i use method prefix?

Comment: for method prefix you should enable DMI, it's disabled by default for safety, if you want to enable it on your own risk see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20772170/573032) answer

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](https://struts.apache.org/docs/processing-forms.html) explains it and [this tutorial](https://struts.apache.org/docs/form-validation.html) shows how to do validation

Method `MethodPrefixAction.execute` should return `success` or `cancel` string.

In `struts.xml` you can redirect user to different pages based on return string:

```
<action name="methodPrefix" class="example.chapter4.MethodPrefixAction">
            <result name="success">/chapter4/methodPrefixResult.jsp</result>
            <result name="cancel">/chapter4/methodPrefix.jsp</result>
        </action>
```